# How to create multiple custom pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am designing a website in wordpress. I have 1 custom home page & another are single themed pages. Now I want to add some more landing pages with different design. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

create new php file in your theme directory, add this on the top of your php file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: your template name
*/
?>
```

use the template by choosing page templates on post option.